# payment amount tracking sql

Tags: sql, math, type-2-dimension

I had this question asked of me on a job interview, and I can't seem to find the right way to do this. I'm just looking for the answer so if it comes up again another time I'll have more of an idea of what should be done.

Table A has 3 columns. ID, CustomerName, and Amount

Values (1, "Someone", 20000)

Table B has 3 Columns. CustID, Date, Payment.
Values

```
(1, 1/1/2014, 100)
(1, 2/1/2014, 200)
(1, 3/1/2014, 500)
(1, 4/1/2014, 175)
```

What they want to know is after each payment has been made, what is the remaining balance on the account. So the output would be:

Customer Name, Payment Amount, Remaining Balance

For each payment.

How would someone go about accomplishing this since I've stumped all of my database friends and can't seem to find the info on google....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In databases that support the ANSI standard cumulative sum syntax, you would simply do:

```
select a.CustomerName, b.Payment,
       (a.amount - sum(b.payment) over (partition by a.id order by date)) as RemainingBalance
from tablea a left outer join
     tableb b
     on a.id = b.id;
```

In other databases, I would use a correlated subquery.

Comment: That's what I was thinking when I got home and started poking around the internet. I'm in the process of installing MSSQL Server 2012 right now, all I have is MySQL running on my pc. I will test this out and let you know. Thank again Gordon!

Comment: The OP updated the question so your last sentence doesn't make sense anymore

Comment: Sorry, I caught it after the fact and updated it. :(

Comment: I created the database structure as outlined in MSSQL2012 Developer, and it gives me the error (The Parallel Data Warehouse (PDW) features are not enabled.)

Comment: @MichaelHarness . . . I don't know what those features have to do with this question.  The above query should run on SQL Server Express, the free version.

Comment: I have no idea either. I've never seen that error before. I ran the query exactly as you created it and that's the error I received.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the problem. And yes, this works perfectly. Thank you so much for your help!